# Is it possible to uninitialize/reinitialize/delete role in testcafe E2E test?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, jquery-cookie

I am using TestCafe for my E2E testing.

Scenario: I am running a test use test runs. For example, first test run executes tests in firefox browser, and next run in chrome (this is just example, I have cases where I need to run e2e tests in different stages as well). I have used a role. When one test run completes, and it is running another test run, still the role cookie persists, and it acts as the user is logged in.

Expected behavior: Roles should be re-initialized for each run.

Is there some way I can clean the cookie, or un-initialize the roles?

Answer (score 3):

The `Role` functionality was created to save time by saving the state of cookies and (local|session)Storage and applying them on the second and subsequent role calls. If you want to perform login actions on each test, just transfer the actions from your role to a separate function and call this function instead of the role. If your goal is different, please add the example that illustrates the current behavior and describe what task you would like to accomplish.

[User Roles documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html).

Comment: My question is bit different from what you just mentioned. I have to run test for different stages, as dev, int, cons etc. So each of this stage different test runs for me. Each test run have n-testcases running. My problem is not when I am running in single stage, I initialized a role in dev, and when I try to run another test run with int, then Role session remains from dev, so it does not login for first assignment of role, rather use the old session. Though url is different (using funtion to call url), since name of role is same, it uses the same.

Comment: You can try to split your stages into fixtures: `dev`, `cons`, and so on. Then, you can use the fixture hooks mechanism: 
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#fixture-hooks
 
You can create a new Role on the `fixture.before` hook. Thus your roles will keep their data during test runs in the same fixture, but will be reinitialized on the next stage.

Comment: But the same test runs for dev, cons and so on, why to separate them? And stages was just an example, I have test to run for site for different countries for example. Is it not possible to reinitialize the role, or delete this cookie. Roles documentation in testcafe does not mention anything like this. This thing will make it easy. Work around at the moment is creating separate role variable in an array according to stages.

Comment: The role mechanism is not intended for clearing the initialized role. I think your workaround is suitable for this issue.